# Rasterio Creating TIFF file

Tags: arrays, numpy, tiff, rasterio

I tried to use the code on the Rasterio-doc website to write an array as a TIFF to disk
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html

```
with rasterio.Env():
    profile = src.profile
    profile.update(
        dtype=rasterio.uint8,
        count=1,
        compress='lzw')

    with rasterio.open('example.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(array.astype(rasterio.uint8), 1)
```

When I run the code the following error occurs: 'name 'array' is not defined'.

I tried in the last line with 'np.array' instead of 'array' to say that it is a numpy-array but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable 'array' stands for the data that should be written to disk. Create a numpy array as for example:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array(my_array_data)
```

Then you can write this data to disk as described in the tutorial.